# Subtract rows in a grouped Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and i need to subtract rows if they have the same group.

Input Dataframe:

| A | B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 10.0 |
| A1 | B1 | 5.0 |
| A1 | B2 | 5.0 |
| A2 | B1 | 3.0 |
| A2 | B1 | 5.0 |
| A2 | B2 | 1.0 |

Expected Dataframe:

| A | B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 5.0 |
| A1 | B2 | 5.0 |
| A2 | B1 | -2.0 |
| A2 | B2 | 1.0 |

**Logic**: For example the first and second rows of the dataframe are in group A1 and B1 so the value must be 10.0 - 5.0 = 5.0. 4º and 5º rows have the same group as well so the value must be 3.0 - 5.0 = -2.0.

Only subtract rows if they have same A and B value.

Thank you!

Comment: explain what's the logic

Comment: What assumptions are there on the data? Are there at most 2 rows for each (A, B) pair? Are these two rows always adjacent or could they be spread out? Should the subtraction always be in the order these rows appear?

Comment: There are max 2 row for each pair (A,B). And these rows always are adjacents. And the subtraction always be in the order these rows appear. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
subtract = lambda x: x.iloc[0] - (x.iloc[1] if len(x) == 2 else 0)
out = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Value'].apply(subtract).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output:
    A   B  Value
0  A1  B1    5.0
1  A1  B2    5.0
2  A2  B1   -2.0
3  A2  B2    1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can prepare duplicated rows to be substracted and then sum after grouping. This works for more than one duplicated row in the correct order, too.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/70438208/14277722')[0]

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['A','B']), 'Value'] *=-1
df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Output

```
    A   B  Value
0  A1  B1    5.0
1  A1  B2    5.0
2  A2  B1   -2.0
3  A2  B2    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us pass the condition within `groupby` `apply`

```
out = df.groupby(['A','B'])['Value'].apply(lambda x : x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[-1] if len(x)>1 else x.iloc[0]).reset_index(name = 'Value')
Out[18]: 
    A   B  Value
0  A1  B1    5.0
1  A1  B2    5.0
2  A2  B1   -2.0
3  A2  B2    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use numpy's reduce function:

```py
df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index = False).Value.agg(np.subtract.reduce)
 
    A   B  Value
0  A1  B1    5.0
1  A1  B2    5.0
2  A2  B1   -2.0
3  A2  B2    1.0
```